# Fetching the data from one Source-Org, and performing DML operation form Destination org to Source -org

Tags: apex, salesforce-to-salesforce

Using Connected apps i can able to get the data from One to another.

### This is my code, and its working fine.[ the code which is shown here is the dummy object and fileds not the actual ones].

My Actual requirment is .....
From OneORG( say ORG-A) i need to get the data and display in Another Org(say ORG-B) 
After doing business logic again i need to upsert the data from   ORG-B to ORG-A.

### I should not use any login id/ password in the code or in custom settings.

In the below code i used id and pwd :-(

```
public with sharing class FetchEmpl {

    //Login Domain
    String LOGIN_DOMAIN = 'www';
    public String pwd{get;set;}
    public String userName{get;set;}
    public custEmployee cEmp{get;set;}
    public String errMsg{get;set;}
    public String displayError{get;set;}

    public  list<records2> listrecords2 = new list<records2>();
    public FetchEmpl ()
    {
        displayError = 'none';
        fetch();
    }

    public void fetch()
    {
        userName='*********';
        pwd='*********';
        errMsg  = 'Some error occurred, please try again';
        try
        {
        //-----------------------------------
        // Login via SOAP/XML web service api
        //-----------------------------------
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://' + LOGIN_DOMAIN + '.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
        //not escaping username and password because we're setting those variables above
        //in other words, this line "trusts" the lines above
        //if username and password were sourced elsewhere, they'd need to be escaped below
        request.setBody('<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>' + userName+ '</username><password>' + pwd+ '</password></login></Body></Envelope>');
        Dom.XmlNode resultElmt = (new Http()).send(request).getBodyDocument().getRootElement()
          .getChildElement('Body', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
          .getChildElement('loginResponse', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com')
          .getChildElement('result', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');

        //-------------------------------
        // Grab session id and server url
        //--------------------------------
        final String SERVER_URL = resultElmt.getChildElement('serverUrl', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') .getText().split('/services')[0];
        final String SESSION_ID = resultElmt.getChildElement('sessionId', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') .getText();

        //----------------------------------
        // Load first 10 accounts via REST API
        //---------------------------------
        final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference(SERVER_URL + '/services/data/v22.0/query/');
        theUrl.getParameters().put('q','Select name,salary__c From employee__c a limit 10');
        request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(theUrl.getUrl());
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + SESSION_ID);

        String body = (new Http()).send(request).getBody();
        system.debug('******body  **********');
        system.debug(body);
        body = body.replace('__c' ,'');
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(body);
        system.debug('******JSONFinalString BEFORE **********');
        string JSONFinalString = JSON.serializePretty(body );
        system.debug('******JSONFinalString **********');
        system.debug(body );

             while (parser.nextToken() != null) {           
           if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
                 cEmp = ( custEmployee )parser.readValueAs(custEmployee.class); 
          }
        }//while closed
       }
       catch(Exception e)
        {
            displayError = 'block';
        }

       system.debug('******wrapper class  **********');
        system.debug(cEmp);

    }
    public class custEmployee{     
public list<records2> records{get;set;}     

    }
    public class records2{
         public string Name{get;set;}
     public string Salary{get;set;}
      public records2(string Name,string Salary){
     this.Name=Name;
     this.Salary=Salary;
     } 
    }
}
```

The problem is i am using Login id and Pwd in the code( we can use custom settings), but i dont want to use any login id and pwd in the code or by using custom settings.

is it possible in Salesforce...can any one guide me

Answer (score 0):

The official, sanctioned way to do this is by way of Salesforce to Salesforce. Simply configure both orgs, map some fields, and you're done.

If that's not sufficient, then you'll need to get creative. There's a few ways to provide access to an org without logging in, ranging from secure to insecure.

Using OAuth2, you can capture a web server login flow, and keep just the refresh token. This will allow perpetual access to the org so long as the user is active and the session isn't revoked. I'd recommend this approach if Salesforce to Salesforce isn't viable. Access can be very long term.

You could also set up Email Services. The orgs can use SMTP to communicate with each other. You only need to store the remote email address, and send those emails. You'll want to use one license per org for a dummy user so you don't hit your external mail daily limit. There are also incoming limits, too, but most orgs will never hit those limits. This is better than nothing, but still requires some security precautions, like filtering by email address and requiring secure connections.

Finally, you could provide Guest access via a Site. Simply create a Site, set up code or pages that can be accessed, and use those to transfer data. I'd suggest using IP address filters or other means of protecting your org, because anyone that figures out your Sites URL can access your data. Seriously, I'd recommend against this, because you're intentionally bypassing all security at this point. At minimum, configure the guest to use only the fields, objects, pages, and classes necessary to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Apex Class:-

```
enter preformatted text here

public class FetchAccountController {

    //Login Domain May be test, prerellogin.pre
    String LOGIN_DOMAIN = 'ap2';
    public String pwd{get;set;}
    public String userName{get;set;}
    public List<Account> acc{get;set;}
    public String errMsg{get;set;}
    public String displayError{get;set;}
    //public list<wrapperClassForProduct> AccountWrapperList{get;set;}

    public FetchAccountController()
    {
        displayError = 'none';
    }

    public void fetch()
    {
        errMsg  = 'Some error occurred, please try again';
        try
        {
        //-----------------------------------
        // Login via SOAP/XML web service api
        //-----------------------------------
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://' + LOGIN_DOMAIN + '.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
        //not escaping username and password because we're setting those variables above
        //in other words, this line "trusts" the lines above
        //if username and password were sourced elsewhere, they'd need to be escaped below
        request.setBody('<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>' + userName+ '</username><password>' + pwd+ '</password></login></Body></Envelope>');
        Dom.XmlNode resultElmt = (new Http()).send(request).getBodyDocument().getRootElement()
          .getChildElement('Body', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
          .getChildElement('loginResponse', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com')
          .getChildElement('result', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');
          system.debug('****'+resultElmt);



        //-------------------------------
        // Grab session id and server url
        //--------------------------------
        final String SERVER_URL = resultElmt.getChildElement('serverUrl', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') .getText().split('/services')[0];
        final String SESSION_ID = resultElmt.getChildElement('sessionId', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') .getText();

        //----------------------------------
        // Load first 20 accounts via REST API
        //---------------------------------
        final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference(SERVER_URL + '/services/data/v22.0/query/');
        theUrl.getParameters().put('q','Select a.Phone, a.Name, a.CreatedBy.FirstName, a.CreatedById From Account a limit 20');
        request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(theUrl.getUrl());
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + SESSION_ID);

        String body = (new Http()).send(request).getBody();

        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(body);

        do{
            parser.nextToken();
        }while(parser.hasCurrentToken() && !'records'.equals(parser.getCurrentName()));

        parser.nextToken();

        acc = (List<Account>) parser.readValueAs(List<Account>.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            displayError = 'block';
        }

    }
    public void insertAccount(){
        list<Account> accountToUpdate = new list<Account>();
        for(Account aaa : acc){
            Account accObj = new Account ();
            accObj.name = aaa.name;
            accountToUpdate.add(accObj);
        }
        insert accountToUpdate;
    }

}
```

if the Object contain any External Id. On the basic of external Id you can also Upsert same as Insert Operations